# C#. Byte gets messed up when going to -> ArraySegment -> internet -> Stream -> back to byte

Tags: c#, arrays, stream, byte

I have a grid based multiplayer game. The backend service I'm using has an option to send structured data packets or unstructured ones. I've implemented all the netcode using structured data and am now replacing more frequent calls with unstructured data (which are smaller, as they're byte arrays)

my game grid is less than 16 high and wide, so for a move call I only need to send one byte. The Leftmost 4 bits are the X value, the Rightmost 4 bits are the Y value.

I have some methods to convert a 2d coordinate in my game into a single byte and back. These methods have unit tests and seem to work perfectly.
Here they are...

```
public static byte CoordToByte(Coord cord)
{
   byte pos = (byte)(cord.x <<4) ;
    pos += (byte)cord.y;
    return pos;
}


public static Coord ByteToCoord(byte input)
{
    return new Coord(input >> 4,input & 0x0F);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I send and receive the data over the internet using the backend service something goes wrong. Whenever one player sends an X value of 8 or more I always receive the value 11111101 on the other end, it doesnt matter what the Y value is.

Heres the code I'm using to send and receive the unstructured data. To send data the backend service requires you to send An ArraySegment of bytes
And when receiving data the payload comes as a Stream class.

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong here but I dont know.

```
//SENDING POSITION

ArraySegment<byte> unstructuredData = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[]{CoordTools.CoordToByte(here)});

//GETTING POSITION

byte fromthem = (byte)_packet.Stream.ReadByte();
Coord moveto =  CoordTools.ByteToCoord(fromthem)
```

Comment: Maybe your Stream.ReadByte returns -1 indicating end of stream? When casted to byte like you do it will be 11111111

Comment: I dont think its that cus If I call read readbyte a 2nd time on recieving the stream I do get that. Whats really annoying is that this all works fine for X values under 8

Comment: Well even if it's not that - worth handling this case and not jus lt cast to byte. It returns int and not byte for a reason.

Comment: Just fyi, motivated by ure comment I printed out the int before casting it and its the same, 11111101